# Making Margins 1 inch all the way around

Tags: margins, fontsize, textwidth

1. Hi everyone,
   I created an account just to ask this question as it is really important. Several places that I am applying to require my CV to have 1 inch margins all the way around (on all sides).
   I'm using a LaTeX template I found online to type up my CV as I really like the way it looks. However, on the Template in the comments it says %adjust margins to 0.5 in all sides, so I think the margins for this template are 0.5 inch.   I need, however (very important) for the margins to be 1 inch on all sides.
   Here is the source code (note: The information in the Cv here is just random information):
2. Now follows a code block:

   ```
   \documentclass[letterpaper,10pt]{article}
   %-----------------------------------------------------------
   \usepackage[empty]{fullpage}
   \usepackage{color}
   \definecolor{mygrey}{gray}{0.80}
   \raggedbottom
   \raggedright
   \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0in}

   % Adjust margins to 0.5in on all sides
   \addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.5in}
   \addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-0.5in}
   \addtolength{\textwidth}{1.0in}
   \addtolength{\topmargin}{-0.5in}
   \addtolength{\textheight}{1.0in}

   %-----------------------------------------------------------
   %Custom commands
   \newcommand{\resitem}[1]{\item #1 \vspace{-2pt}}
   \newcommand{\resheading}[1]{{\large \colorbox{mygrey} 
   {\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}{\textbf{#1 \vphantom{p\^{E}}}}\end{minipage}}}}
   \newcommand{\ressubheading}[4]{
   \begin{tabular*}{7.0in}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
   \textbf{#1} & \textit{#4} \\
   \end{tabular*}\vspace{-6pt}}

   \newcommand{\ressubheadinged}[4]{
   \begin{tabular*}{7.0in}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
   \textbf{#1} & #2 \\
   \textit{#3} & \textit{#4}\\
   \end{tabular*}\vspace{-6pt}}
   %-----------------------------------------------------------
   \begin{document}

   \begin{tabular*}{7.5in}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
   \textbf{\large Bob Mars}\\
   888.888.8888\\
   bobmars@gmail.com
   \end{tabular*}
   \\

   \vspace{0.1in}

   \resheading{Education}
   \begin{itemize}
   \item
   \ressubheading{University}{}{}{September 2000 - June 2004}
   \begin{itemize}
   \item B.S., Engineering
   \end{itemize}
   \end{itemize}

   \resheading{Work Experience}

   \begin{itemize}
   \item
   \ressubheading{Company 1}{Seattle, WA}{Engineer}{Engineer, June 
   2016 - Present}
   \begin{itemize}
   \item Engineer for Company 1
   \item Did engineering work for Company 1.
   \item Investigated different things. Overall, a great experience 
   that I truly valued and enjoyed.  The projects I worked on were 
   my favorites.
   \end{itemize}
   \item
   \ressubheading{Company 2}{Seattle,WA}{Engineer}{June 2014- June 
   2015}
   \begin{itemize}
   \item Worked on various projects
   \item Used various programs. The programs I used were difficult 
   to learn at first but I soon adapted and things came more 
   naturally to me.
   \item Received high marks for all my work. My work was 
   collaborative and highly enjoyable.  The best experience of my 
   life.
   \item Worked for several years. A rigorous and difficult, but 
   pleasant experience. Overall, the best experience of my life. 
   Highly enjoyed.
   \item Employee of the month twice. Both were my highest-achieving 
   awards during the job. Truly enjoyed the entire experience.
   \end{itemize}
   \item
   \ressubheading{Company 3}{Seattle,WA}{Engineer}{Engineer, June 
   2012- June 2014}
   \begin{itemize}
   \item Engineer for Company 3 for over two years.  A rigorous but 
   pleasant experience.
   \item Worked on 3 projects.  All three projects were nuanced but 
   highly interesting in their own right.  A wonderful experience 
   that I truly enjoyed.
   \item Used various programs. The programs I used were difficult 
   to learn at first but I soon adapted and things came more 
   naturally to me.
   \item Discovered important relationships between various things.
   \item Worked for several years on various projects. A rigorous, 
   but pleasant experience. Overall, the best experience of my life.  
   \item Figured out things nicely.
   \item Promoted twice.
   \item won award.
   \end{itemize}

   \item
   \ressubheading{Company 4}{Seattle,WA}{Engineer}{Engineer, June 
   2010-June 2012}
   \begin{itemize}
   \item{Engineer for Company 4.}
   \item{Awarded best employee twice.}
   \item{Used various programs. Was a great experience, that I 
   valued greatly.  Company 4 is a great company to work for. I love 
   the projects that I worked on.}
   \item{Won awards for my work. Worked on various projects with 
   various people. Overall, a great experience that I truly valued 
   and appreciated. }
   \item{A pleasant experience.}
   \end{itemize}
   \end{itemize}

   \resheading{Volunteer}
   \begin{itemize}
   \item
   \ressubheading{Organization 1}{Seattle,WA}{Volunteer}{June 2016}
   \begin{itemize}
   \item{Recycled and helped the community in organization 1 on many 
   things. Was a great experience that I really enjoyed.  }
   \item{Worked for over two years in the same organization. We did 
   many things including beach cleanups, recycling events, various 
   events for the community.}
   \item{Set up various events for the community and played a huge 
   role in leading this organization. Had several leadership 
   positions}.
   \end{itemize}

   \item
   \ressubheading{Organization 2}{Seattle, WA}{Volunteer}{June 2015}
   \begin{itemize}
   \item{Worked for this organization for over 3 years. We cleaned 
   up trash in the community and hosted several events.}
   \item{A great experience.  Some of the best memories of my life 
   occurred while  volunteering for this organization.}
   \end{itemize}

   \end{itemize}


   \end{document}
   ```

3.This is how the document looks like currently: [image]

4.All I need is for the margins to just be 1 inch on all sides without the document looking weird. Thanks so much!!

5.This is how the document looks if I try using the \usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}: (it's almost as if everything is left justified):
[image]

6.Is there a way to make the margins 1in by altering the code:

```
   \addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.5in}
   \addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-0.5in}
   \addtolength{\textwidth}{1.0in}
   \addtolength{\topmargin}{-0.5in}
   \addtolength{\textheight}{1.0in}
```

7. [image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Did you try `\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}`?

Comment: I tried using that (after googling) but when I do the formatting becomes really weird. Like the margin on the left looks much bigger than the margin on the right.

Comment: @marmot I updated the question to include how weird it looks if I use \usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. Remove the line

   ```
    \usepackage{fullpage}
   ```
2. Remove all the lines modifying the margins (in 6. in your question).
3. Add the lines

   ```
    \usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
    \pagestyle{empty}
   ```
4. Globally replace `7.0in` with `\linewidth`.
5. Replace `\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}` with `\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep}` (thanks to Max for catching this.)
6. Recompile.

### Some explanation

The `fullpage` package is a rather old package to set margins to either 1" or 1.5", plus a couple of other settings to do with pagestyles.  The option `[empty]` sets the document page style to `empty` (i.e., no page numbers).  Since `geometry` is a much more general package, it makes sense to use it instead. We therefore have to add an explicit `\pagestyle` command to mimic the `fullpage` option.

The template you're copying also added manual corrections to the margins to make the margins .5", which kind of defeats the purpose of using `fullpage` in the first place.

It then hard coded values for `tabular` constructs in the document to the width of the text assuming the .5" margins. By changing this hard coded value to `\linewidth` you make the tabluars adjust independent of the margin settings.

Max's suggestion changes one other setting to make sure that the `\resheading` command doesn't produce an overfull box, i.e., exceed the actual text width.

Here's a full example:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,10pt]{article}
%-----------------------------------------------------------
% Delete this line
%\usepackage[empty]{fullpage}

% Add these lines:
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}


\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{mygrey}{gray}{0.80}
\raggedbottom
\raggedright
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0in}

% Delete these lines
% Adjust margins to 0.5in on all sides
%\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.5in}
%\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-0.5in}
%\addtolength{\textwidth}{1.0in}
%\addtolength{\topmargin}{-0.5in}
%\addtolength{\textheight}{1.0in}

%-----------------------------------------------------------
%Custom commands
\newcommand{\resitem}[1]{\item #1 \vspace{-2pt}}
\newcommand{\resheading}[1]{{\large \colorbox{mygrey} 
{\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep}{\textbf{#1 \vphantom{p\^{E}}}}\end{minipage}}}}
\newcommand{\ressubheading}[4]{
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
\textbf{#1} & \textit{#4} \\
\end{tabular*}\vspace{-6pt}}

\newcommand{\ressubheadinged}[4]{
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
\textbf{#1} & #2 \\
\textit{#3} & \textit{#4}\\
\end{tabular*}\vspace{-6pt}}
%-----------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular*}{7.5in}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
\textbf{\large Bob Mars}\\
888.888.8888\\
bobmars@gmail.com
\end{tabular*}
\\

\vspace{0.1in}

\resheading{Education}
\begin{itemize}
\item
\ressubheading{University}{}{}{September 2000 - June 2004}
\begin{itemize}
\item B.S., Engineering
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}

\resheading{Work Experience}

\begin{itemize}
\item
\ressubheading{Company 1}{Seattle, WA}{Engineer}{Engineer, June 
2016 - Present}
\begin{itemize}
\item Engineer for Company 1
\item Did engineering work for Company 1.
\item Investigated different things. Overall, a great experience 
that I truly valued and enjoyed.  The projects I worked on were 
my favorites.
\end{itemize}
\item
\ressubheading{Company 2}{Seattle,WA}{Engineer}{June 2014- June 
2015}
\begin{itemize}
\item Worked on various projects
\item Used various programs. The programs I used were difficult 
to learn at first but I soon adapted and things came more 
naturally to me.
\item Received high marks for all my work. My work was 
collaborative and highly enjoyable.  The best experience of my 
life.
\item Worked for several years. A rigorous and difficult, but 
pleasant experience. Overall, the best experience of my life. 
Highly enjoyed.
\item Employee of the month twice. Both were my highest-achieving 
awards during the job. Truly enjoyed the entire experience.
\end{itemize}
\item
\ressubheading{Company 3}{Seattle,WA}{Engineer}{Engineer, June 
2012- June 2014}
\begin{itemize}
\item Engineer for Company 3 for over two years.  A rigorous but 
pleasant experience.
\item Worked on 3 projects.  All three projects were nuanced but 
highly interesting in their own right.  A wonderful experience 
that I truly enjoyed.
\item Used various programs. The programs I used were difficult 
to learn at first but I soon adapted and things came more 
naturally to me.
\item Discovered important relationships between various things.
\item Worked for several years on various projects. A rigorous, 
but pleasant experience. Overall, the best experience of my life.  
\item Figured out things nicely.
\item Promoted twice.
\item won award.
\end{itemize}

\item
\ressubheading{Company 4}{Seattle,WA}{Engineer}{Engineer, June 
2010-June 2012}
\begin{itemize}
\item{Engineer for Company 4.}
\item{Awarded best employee twice.}
\item{Used various programs. Was a great experience, that I 
valued greatly.  Company 4 is a great company to work for. I love 
the projects that I worked on.}
\item{Won awards for my work. Worked on various projects with 
various people. Overall, a great experience that I truly valued 
and appreciated. }
\item{A pleasant experience.}
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}

\resheading{Volunteer}
\begin{itemize}
\item
\ressubheading{Organization 1}{Seattle,WA}{Volunteer}{June 2016}
\begin{itemize}
\item{Recycled and helped the community in organization 1 on many 
things. Was a great experience that I really enjoyed.  }
\item{Worked for over two years in the same organization. We did 
many things including beach cleanups, recycling events, various 
events for the community.}
\item{Set up various events for the community and played a huge 
role in leading this organization. Had several leadership 
positions}.
\end{itemize}

\item
\ressubheading{Organization 2}{Seattle, WA}{Volunteer}{June 2015}
\begin{itemize}
\item{Worked for this organization for over 3 years. We cleaned 
up trash in the community and hosted several events.}
\item{A great experience.  Some of the best memories of my life 
occurred while  volunteering for this organization.}
\end{itemize}

\end{itemize}


\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Also replace `\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}` with `\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep}` to prevent overfull hboxes.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this and let you know how it turns out.  So for 4. for everyline that has 7.0 in it, I replace with \linewidth? Thanks

Comment: @bobbob Yes, modulo the addition that I've added based on Max's comment.

Comment: Why did someone downvote this?

Comment: I upvoted it, but I don't think my upvote shows since I have less than 15 reputation.thanks for the help.

Comment: @AlanMunn I only upvoted. Can't see why anyone would downvote.

Comment: @AlanMunn I updated my question with point 7. with a picture of how it looks like now. do you think this is how i should look like (for 1 inch margins)? thanks so much again!

Comment: @bobbob I don't see your edit.  I'll add a screen shot of what my output looks like.

Comment: @bobbob You can add the `showframe` option to the `geometry` package just to check where the margins are. Don't forget to remove the option when sending your resumé to a potential employer :)

Answer (score 4):

I modified the template. Does it produce what you want?

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,10pt]{article}
%-----------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage[empty]{fullpage}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{mygrey}{gray}{0.80}
\raggedbottom
\raggedright
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0in}
\usepackage[margin = 1in]{geometry}

%-----------------------------------------------------------
%Custom commands
\newcommand{\resitem}[1]{\item #1 \vspace{-2pt}}
\newcommand{\resheading}[1]{{\large \colorbox{mygrey}
{\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep}{\textbf{#1 \vphantom{p\^{E}}}}\end{minipage}}}}
\newcommand{\ressubheading}[4]{%
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
\textbf{#1} & \textit{#4} \\
\end{tabular*}\vspace{-6pt}}

\newcommand{\ressubheadinged}[4]{
\begin{tabular*}{l\linewidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
\textbf{#1} & #2 \\
\textit{#3} & \textit{#4}\\
\end{tabular*}\vspace{-6pt}}
%-----------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
\textbf{\large Bob Mars}\\
888.888.8888\\
bobmars@gmail.com
\end{tabular*}
\\

\vspace{0.1in}

\resheading{Education}
\begin{itemize}
\item
\ressubheading{University}{}{}{September 2000 - June 2004}
\begin{itemize}
\item B.S., Engineering
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}

\resheading{Work Experience}

\begin{itemize}
\item
\ressubheading{Company 1}{Seattle, WA}{Engineer}{Engineer, June
2016 - Present}
\begin{itemize}
\item Engineer for Company 1
\item Did engineering work for Company 1.
\item Investigated different things. Overall, a great experience
that I truly valued and enjoyed. The projects I worked on were
my favorites.
\end{itemize}
\item
\ressubheading{Company 2}{Seattle,WA}{Engineer}{June 2014- June
2015}
\begin{itemize}
\item Worked on various projects
\item Used various programs. The programs I used were difficult
to learn at first but I soon adapted and things came more
naturally to me.
\item Received high marks for all my work. My work was
collaborative and highly enjoyable. The best experience of my
life.
\item Worked for several years. A rigorous and difficult, but
pleasant experience. Overall, the best experience of my life.
Highly enjoyed.
\item Employee of the month twice. Both were my highest-achieving
awards during the job. Truly enjoyed the entire experience.
\end{itemize}
\item
\ressubheading{Company 3}{Seattle,WA}{Engineer}{Engineer, June
2012- June 2014}
\begin{itemize}
\item Engineer for Company 3 for over two years. A rigorous but
pleasant experience.
\item Worked on 3 projects. All three projects were nuanced but
highly interesting in their own right. A wonderful experience
that I truly enjoyed.
\item Used various programs. The programs I used were difficult
to learn at first but I soon adapted and things came more
naturally to me.
\item Discovered important relationships between various things.
\item Worked for several years on various projects. A rigorous,
but pleasant experience. Overall, the best experience of my life.
\item Figured out things nicely.
\item Promoted twice.
\item won award.
\end{itemize}

\item
\ressubheading{Company 4}{Seattle,WA}{Engineer}{Engineer, June
2010-June 2012}
\begin{itemize}
\item{Engineer for Company 4.}
\item{Awarded best employee twice.}
\item{Used various programs. Was a great experience, that I
valued greatly. Company 4 is a great company to work for. I love
the projects that I worked on.}
\item{Won awards for my work. Worked on various projects with
various people. Overall, a great experience that I truly valued
and appreciated. }
\item{A pleasant experience.}
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}

\resheading{Volunteer}
\begin{itemize}
\item
\ressubheading{Organization 1}{Seattle,WA}{Volunteer}{June 2016}
\begin{itemize}
\item{Recycled and helped the community in organization 1 on many
things. Was a great experience that I really enjoyed. }
\item{Worked for over two years in the same organization. We did
many things including beach cleanups, recycling events, various
events for the community.}
\item{Set up various events for the community and played a huge
role in leading this organization. Had several leadership
positions}.
\end{itemize}

\item
\ressubheading{Organization 2}{Seattle, WA}{Volunteer}{June 2015}
\begin{itemize}
\item{Worked for this organization for over 3 years. We cleaned
up trash in the community and hosted several events.}
\item{A great experience. Some of the best memories of my life
occurred while volunteering for this organization.}
\end{itemize}

\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Looks good, thanks @Bernard.  I just want to verify with someone if the margins are now 1inch (just to be careful) as apparently employers are really particular about this. Are the margins in the picture you posted 1 inch (just to be sure)? Thanks so much!

Comment: @bobbob: as far as I can trust my pdfviewer, they're 1.00 in. If you want to measure on paper, add the option `showframe` to `geometry`.

Comment: How is this different from my answer?

Comment: How do I add the option showframe to geometry as far as the code @Bernard?

Comment: Mmm…I've taken a look at your code. Indeed, iy seems the single difference is ìn the first  `tabularx* – I set its width to `\textwidth`, to have 0 bas boxes.  Nothing findamentally different. Should I delete it?

Comment: @bobbob: Just complete `\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}` as  `\usepackage[margin=1in, showframe]{geometry}`.